# Confused about complexity classes?

Tags: math, time-complexity, complexity-theory, computer-science, formal-languages

My book uses this definition for the Polynomial complexity class (L is a binary language):

[image: Definition]

But by this definition, don't all languages belong to the polynomial complexity class? Because if I define A to be 1 for all languages, then A would decide all L in constant time (and therefore polynomial time), since it would return 1 immediately, meaning all languages would belong to polynomial complexity.

Why is my logic incorrect?

Comment: Give us more context. What does the definition mean "decide L"? Anyway the flaw in your argument is that A = 1 won't "decide" L in most cases.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on Theoretical CS Stack Exchange

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding, "A decides L" means that the algorithm A decides if a given word w belongs to L. Under that assumption, letting A always return true does not make sense because this algorithm could only decide the language that contains every possible word. This wouldn't be an algorithm for any other language.